# Unreal Engine 4 problems with intelliSence

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am new to unreal Engine 4, and I am trying to create c++ class. It creates files sucsessfully, but `InteliSence` does not work, even if I type `in`, there is not `int` suggestion. All i found was this [question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/809801/ue420-is-missing-the-intellisense-includepath-for.html), but I do not have similar patch in my Engine folder.
I use the lastest eigne version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code:
When I create a new class from within the Unreal Editor, `IntelliSense` won't properly read the code and will generate errors such as not finding include files.

Either reopening Visual Studio, or a refresh from within the Unreal Editor ( Files > Refresh Visual Studio Project ) usually does the trick.

If that will not help, there's an error within `Unreal 4.25` that will make the boilerplate code generate the wrong directory at `#include "folder/myclass.h"`. `IntelliSense` might not read any further than that.
Typing the correct directory and refreshing with the methods mentioned above fixes that for me.